# Scrollview not loading additional Images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIView that I am using as a simple onboarding view. I simply shows `n` images, that the user can swipe through.

The only image that loads is the very first image "OnBoard-1". The other images are there when I debug the what is being added to the image view.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface OnBoardingView : UIView 
- (void)setImages:(NSArray *)newImages;
@end
```

Here is the .m file

```
#import "OnBoardingView.h"

@interface OnBoardingView () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    NSArray *contentImages;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray       *contentImages;
@end



@implementation OnBoardingView


@synthesize pageControl;
@synthesize contentImages;


- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) { }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Override contentImages setter

- (void)setImages:(NSArray *)newImages {
    if (newImages != self.contentImages) {
        self.contentImages = newImages;
        [self setup];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Carousel setup

- (void)setup {
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setBounces:NO];

    CGSize scrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.contentImages count]; i++) {
        CGRect slideRect = CGRectMake(scrollViewSize.width * i, 0, scrollViewSize.width, scrollViewSize.height);

        UIView *slide = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:slideRect];
        [slide setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0]];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.contentImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
        NSLog(@"Image named: %@", [self.contentImages objectAtIndex:i]);
        [slide addSubview:imageView];

        [scrollView addSubview:slide];

    }

    UIPageControl *tempPageControll = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, scrollViewSize.height - 20, scrollViewSize.width, 20)];
    [self setPageControl:tempPageControll];

    [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:[self.contentImages count]];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollViewSize.width * [self.contentImages count], scrollViewSize.height)];

    [self addSubview:scrollView];

    [self addSubview:self.pageControl];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:page];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

You initialise the `imageView` with the frame of the `scrollView`, that's in any case not right and may be the cause of your problem.

BTW:

Your property handling looks a bit strange (why the synthesizing instead of just using a normal property only?), and why do you compare the arrays by pointer (`newImages != self.contentImages`)?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the images in paging directly you can assign the number of pages count.And apply the swipe gesture(left and right) to imageview.And based on left and right swipe,you can change the image of imageview.